# How to jailbreak iPhone 5s

Tags: jailbreak, iphone

Can anyone tell me where I can get the instructions to jail break my Iphone5s running iOS 7.1?

I have not been able to do it, tried different sites but is still not working...

Comment: There a plenty of methods and descriptions on the web.

Comment: What iOS do you have, what mac with what OSX ect..now Google that and you will find instructions like http://www.idownloadblog.com/2013/12/22/how-to-jailbreak-ios7-for-macs/comment-page-1/  or others

Answer (score 2):

As of the time of this writing, for iOS 7.0 through 7.0.6 on iPhone 5s, use the ever-simple [evasi0n](http://evasi0n.com) tool; if you have any versions above that, you're out of luck, because there has yet to be a jailbreak developed for them.